# Acquia Stage Environment Clone

Tags: drupal-7, acquia

I am been using Acquia trial account. I have setup the project repository  on the same. Now I want to clone the staging environment on my local machine but I am able to do that whereas I am able to clone dev environment successfully as per the mention steps.

Can anyone please help with the steps for cloning the Acquia Stage Environment.

Comment: Can't you just copy the database via the Cloud and pull the branch via git?